# SharedPreferences & boolean

Tags: android, editor, boolean, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to set the "isPhysicalTheftEnabled" to false when a method is executed, but this doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any idea?

```
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `ed.commit()`.

i.e.:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false);
ed.commit();
```

`SharedPreferences.Editor`s require that you commit anything you change in your SharedPreferences for the changes to apply.

**Regarding your comment on Ankit's answer:**

To set the checked property of your `CheckBox` based on the value of the boolean you saved to `SharedPreferences`, you need something like:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
myCheckBox.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("isPhysicsTheftEnabled", [true/false]);
```

.. in which you pick either `true` or `false` for the `def_value` of `.getBoolean()` (if the `SharedPreferences` can't find the boolean).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ed.apply()` after changing values in `SharedPreferences`.

You can also use `ed.commit()` if you want to check for errors. `commit()` (unlike `apply()`) returns false if the data was not (correctly) written to the persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `editorObject.commit();` after you done with putting data into SP.

For your problem replace your code with below code...

```
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false);
        ed.commit();
```

Comment: I did a .commit(); already but the checkbox still didn't get unchecked, any idea why?

Comment: Post us that chunk of code.  Are you correctly getting the boolean from `SharedPreferences` and setting the `.setChecked()` of the CheckBox to the value of that boolean?

Comment: When you do not use a `PreferenceActivity` you have to set the `CheckBox` state manually via `checkBoxObject.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isPhysicalTheftEnabled", false))`